# Slow response times from free web app server every day at same time

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Every day at about ***3:00PM-4:00PM GMT*** the response times start to increase (no memory increase or CPU increase)
There is a azure availability test going to server every 10 minutes.

As this is a dev site there is no traffic to it other than me (at the odd time) and the availability test
I log to a variable internally the startup time and this shows that the site is not restarting

The first request via a browser when this starts happening is very slow (2 minutes - probably some timeout).
After that it runs perfectly. That seems like the site is shutting down and then starting up on first request, but the pings are keeping it alive so the site is not shutting down (as far as I know)
On the odd log entry I get - I seem to be getting ***502 errors*** - but I can't confirm this as the FEEB logs are usually off at this time.

**FREB logs** turn off automatically after 1 hour and as this is the middle of the night for me (NZDT) - I don't get a chance to turn on.

See attached images - as you can see the response times just increase at same time
Ignore the requests where they are above 20 - thats me going to it via browser
I always check the azure dashboard BEFORE viewing site in browser

Just got this error (from web browser randomly - keep accessing the same page:
502: The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.

**Other relevant Info (Perhaps):**

- I initially had the availability test ping going to a ping endpoint /ping that only returned a 200 and empty string when I noticed this happening
  It now points to the sites homepage to see if it changed anything - still the same.
- Assuming the database is not the issue as the /ping endpoint doesn't touch the database - just a straight controller return.
  Internal Exception handling is catching nothing
  Service: Azure Free Web App (Development)
- There are no web jobs or timed events on this site

[Azure Dashboard Initial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sch2N.png)

**Current tests:**

- Uploading as new site to a **Basic 1 Small**
- Restarting dev site 12 hours before issues (usually 20 hours before)

**Results:**

- Restarting free web-app 12ish hours before issue - same result at same time - so its not the app slowly overloading or it would me much later
- Basic 1 Small: **no problems** - could it be something with the dev server ?

[Azure Dashboard From Today](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWdUG.png)

**Observations:**

Same behavior with /ping endpoint (just return empty string 200 Ok) and Main home page endpoint (database lookups [w/caching] / razer)

If anyone has any ideas what might be going on - I would very much appreciate it
:-)

**Update:**
It seems to of stopped (on its own) about 11/1/2016 1:50:49 AM GMT - my internal timestamp says it restarted - and then the errors started again same time as usual. **Note:** no-one is using the app. The basic 1 Small Server is still going fine.

Sorry I can't add anymore images (not enough rep)

Answer (score 1):

By default, web apps are unloaded if they are idle for some period of time, which could cause the web site slow response during this period of time. Besides, [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-troubleshoot-http-502-http-503/) is about troubleshooting HTTP "502 Bad Gateway" error or a HTTP "503 Service Unavailable" error in Azure web apps, you could read it. And  from the article we could know scaling the web app could mitigate the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That was initially what I thought, but the testing shows that is not the case. The availability test (ping) is keeping it alive/awake. The internal startup time-stamp is also saying it not restarting. The issue shows up at a specific time which was why I did the restart 12ish hours before to cover the bases your talking about. Also the slow/bad responses keep happening until a restart of the app. I had already read that article :-) - but your response is appreciated.